# Remove Test Sends from Send Summary API response

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, fuel-sdk

Using FuelSDK-Python to return a 'Send' api object type, doesn't provide me with any attribute to distinguish 'Test Sends' from others.  In looking through the wsdl, I don't see any attribute which would describe this.  Anyone else have any luck filtering these out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know of any attributes that will mark a send as a test send. However one work around might be to filter any sends that meet the criteria `NumberSent > 100`.

We typically don't send any final deployments less than 100, and don't test to more than 100, so this works for us.